# How to capture video frames from Remote Video in Quickblox iOS

Tags: objective-c, webrtc, quickblox

I wants to get screenshot of remote user (remote stream) at run time,
I have tried to get current `CurrentImageContext` with remote view as a parameter of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myRemoteView.bounds.size, myRemoteView.opaque, 0.0f)` with `[myRemoteView drawViewHierarchyInRect:myRemoteView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES]`, but I'm getting blank screen while capturing on run time, any clue on how to proceeds in this regards?
I am using latest version of Quickblox, ios 10 and xcode 8.

This method is called as a callback when remote user connected,

- (void)session:(QBRTCSession *)session receivedRemoteVideoTrack:(QBRTCVideoTrack *)videoTrack fromUser:(NSNumber *)userID{

  QBRTCVideoTrack *remoteVideoTrak=[self.session remoteVideoTrackWithUserID:@(user.ID)];
      QBRTCRemoteVideoView *remoteVideoView = [[QBRTCRemoteVideoView alloc] init];
      remoteVideoView.frame = self.remoteVV.bounds;

  ```
  [remoteVideoView setVideoTrack:remoteVideoTrak];
  [self.remoteVV addSubview:remoteVideoView];
  ```

}

i wana capture 'self.remoteVV' as a screenshot but it always give me a black image.

Comment: Same issue posted on QuickBlox Git Repo at https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues/649, need some workaround

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for taking screen shot of remote stream in same Video conference. It's working for me.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 2.0f);
        [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This helped me to capture the StreamView.

func captureScreen() -> UIImage? {
        guard let streamView = conferenceStreamView else { return nil }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(streamView.bounds.size, false, 0);
        streamView.drawHierarchy(in: streamView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
```